# Randomly delete percentage of observations by group

Tags: r, dplyr

I would like to randomly remove a percentage of observations from my dataset, based on `df$length_group`. I have a list of lengths which are categorised by the length bin that they fall into.

Here are some example data:

```
 length length_group
43.48231        40-45
71.94886        70-75
62.45009        60-65
52.07499        50-55
36.29884        35-40
39.74954        35-40
42.64207        40-45
54.44252        50-55
40.99404        40-45
53.82440        50-55
54.20191        50-55
65.39952        65-70
60.37424        60-65
55.48567        55-60
44.54021        40-45
55.34843        55-60
55.44153        55-60
45.12505        45-50
64.01769        60-65
33.61202        30-35
46.97908        45-50
59.30657        55-60
50.23894        50-55
```

I'd like to be able to delete 59% of the values from each `df$length_group` at **random**, but I'm struggling to work out the best way to do it. I'm not sure whether the best option would be to `sample`, but I would like to permanently remove the observations from the data frame rather than just selecting 50% out.

Comment: This is pretty much the opposite of random sampling, so `sample()` is absolutely one way to do this. E.g. randomly `sample` 59% of the values, and then make a new dataframe containing all _but those_ values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using `group_by` and `sample_frac`.
Basicall, you sample the fraction 1 - 0.59 from each group to get your desired size.

```r
library(dplyr)

# Make some example data
df <- data.frame(length = runif(99, min=41, max = 99), length_group = c(rep("A",60),rep("B",20),rep("C",19)))

# Check the frequency of each group
table(df$length_group)
#> 
#>  A  B  C 
#> 60 20 19

# Sample a fraction from each of the groups
a = df %>% 
  group_by(length_group) %>% 
  sample_frac(size = 1-0.59)

# New table confirms our new frequency of groups
table(a$length_group)
#> 
#>  A  B  C 
#> 25  8  8
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: btw. `sample_frac()` has been superseded, so `slice_sample(prop = 0.5)` would be the dplyr solution forward :)

Comment: Thank you, I wasn't aware of that! I will edit my answer to include that for the future. :)